# stop a continuously being called function in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, setinterval

I am developing an angular application. As part of it, I am calling a function every 10 seconds which makes an API call.

my function looks like

```
  getData(ahu) {
    console.log('In get data function')
    console.log(ahu)
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getDataRealTime(ahu);
    }, 10000);
  }
```

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="getData(L1)">L1</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="getData(L2)">L2</button>
```

So when I click the L1 button, data keeps coming for L1 every 10 sec. Now when I click L2, data of L2 comes but data from L1 is not stopping. I want data from only L1. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Comment: why did you set the intervel ?

Comment: You should use observables to do this. Lots of edge cases here that you will have to handle later that are easier with rxjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `clearInterval` to stop the previous one just before calling `setInterval`:

```
var intervalId;

function getData(ahu) {
    console.log('In get data function')
    console.log(ahu)
    clearInterval(intervalId); // use either global or this.intervalId
    intervalId = setInterval(() => { // same here.
      this.getDataRealTime(ahu);
    }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see this happening, it means you are changing the model in such a way that Angular has to rerun the digest and fire the watches again. In your particular case, you are calling a function that updates a counter, which is displayed on the page. When the counter value changes it runs the digest again, which calls the function that updates the counter, etc